# iPhone - changing UIWebView background color behind the view (bouncing background)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, background

I have a UIWebView with a black content. All my views and subviews are set to black background.

When scrolling the webView to its top or bottom position, I can see a white background appear while the content is bouncing. So how may I force that background also to be black ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure *all* your subviews are set to black? Setting the webview's background color to black *should* work just fine. (It works in my app, if it doesn't work for you, I'll have to check if I do something else...)

```
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Ooops, you are right. I check 3 times my backgrounds, and I missed one.

Answer (score 10):

Set `webview color` to `clearcolor` add then webview `opaque` to `no`.

```
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearcolor];
webview.opaque=NO;
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: +1 that helped me to get rid of white background while page was loading.

Comment: without the opaque i was not getting what i wanted with clearColor